# What is Sinatra::Base responsible for? (i.e. class overview)

Tags: sinatra

I'm learning Sinatra and trying to wrap my brain around `Sinatra::Base`. The [documentation](http://rubydoc.info/gems/sinatra/Sinatra/Base) doesn't readily answer the question:

**What is `Sinatra::Base` responsible for?**

Is there an easy way to think about it? (i.e. maybe there's a good diagram or something?)

Or is the answer just a long list of functionality? (*For example:* "`Sinatra::Base` is responsible for errors, filters, routes, templates, etc, etc.")

Or is it something simple like: "`Sinatra::Base` *is* Sinatra, minus the execution context, `Sinatra::Application`"?

Comment: Hopefully this question is clear. I'll update it as I get answers and feedback. :)

Comment: Hmmm...maybe it's just "`Sinatra::Base` is an easy way to build Rack-aware classes" or "`Sinatra::Base` gives you a way to define classes that conform to Rack's interface requirements."

Answer (score 2):

`Sinatra::Base` is *the* Sinatra without delegation. Consider the following code *with* delegation:

```rb
# app.rb
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
  render :template
end
```

This style gives you option parser for free:

```
$ ruby app.rb -h
Usage: app [options]
    -p port                          set the port (default is 4567)
    -o addr                          set the host (default is localhost)
    -e env                           set the environment (default is development)
    -s server                        specify rack server/handler (default is thin)
    -x                               turn on the mutex lock (default is off)
```

It also starts the server using appropriate Rack handler when you run the script with your application, so you don't have to write any related code.

It works only because `Object` is extended with `Sinatra::Delegator` in `sinatra/main`. See http://git.io/zWl7RA and http://git.io/NxgpBg. It delegates all Sinatra DSL methods to pre-configured instance of `Sinatra::Base`, namely `Sinatra::Application`.

When you write an application in modular style, nothing is delegated. You just inherit the base:

```rb
require 'sinatra/base'

class Application < Sinatra::Base
  get '/'
    render :template
  end
end

Application.run!
```

So, `Sinatra::Base` is currently responsible for implementing all Sinatra DSL methods on top of Rack, Tilt and other dependencies.